# TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Component as below. When i execute the test case for the below component i get the below error although on browser i see element is generated and no error in compilation .

Error :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

```
  at Check.componentDidMount (src/components/Payments/Check.js:42:42)
  at node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:262:25
  at measureLifeCyclePerf (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:73:12)
  at node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:261:11
  at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/CallbackQueue.js:74:22)
  at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.close (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactTestReconcileTransaction.js:34:26)
  at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.closeAll (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/Transaction.js:207:25)
  at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/Transaction.js:154:16)
  at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactTestMount.js:67:27)
  at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/Transaction.js:141:20)
  at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60:26)
```

Check.js

```
export default class Check extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Check';

  static propTypes = {
    check: PropTypes.object,
    translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    countries: PropTypes.object,
    states: PropTypes.object,
    setCheckState: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  onChange = (fieldName, newValue) => {
    let sanitizedFieldName = fieldName.replace('selected', '');
    sanitizedFieldName = sanitizedFieldName.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + sanitizedFieldName.substr(1);
    const newCheckState = {
      ...this.props.check,
      [sanitizedFieldName]: newValue
    };
    this.props.setCheckState(newCheckState, sanitizedFieldName === 'country');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('mainHeader').focus();
  }

  render() {
    const { translate, check, countries, states } = this.props;
    const parentType = 'check';
    const stateObj = states[check.country] || { optionArray: [] };

    return (
        <div>
          <div tabIndex="0" id="mainHeader"><h1 {...resolve(CheckStyles, 'mainHeader')}>
            {translate('PanelPaymentsCheckHeaderText')}
          </h1></div>
          <div {...resolve(CheckStyles, 'bankInfoContainer')}>
            <h3 {...resolve(CheckStyles, 'bankAccountHeader')}>
              {translate('PanelPaymentsCheckSubHeaderText')}
            </h3>
            ........
            ........                
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not use ids in your ReactJS applications, and you should not acces the DOM directly, because ReactJS manages it all. You should use the provided API, like refs or findDOMNode.

Comment: how do you expect `focus()` should work for `<div>` at all?

Answer (score 4):

I added null check to get rid of the error . It was such a silly fix.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if(this.refs.mainHeader){
  this.refs.mainHeader.focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: But, what's the root cause of the error?

Answer (score 1):

try using a `ref` in place of the `id`, i.e.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.mainHeader.focus();
}
```

...

```
<div tabIndex="0" ref="mainHeader"><h1 {...resolve(CheckStyles, 'mainHeader')}>
```

Comment: I did as u mentioned but still getting the same error

Comment: is the `render` you posted up to date? the only way the ref wouldn't exist is if `mainHeader` is conditionally rendered